# Writing correct SQL query in extra() modifier in django queryset

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, django-queryset

I need help in writing some SQL for an extra() modifier used within a django queryset. Getting stuck in elegantly framing it, several retries have led to dead-ends. Help!

Background: I have a website where people submit interesting URLs (called Link in my models.py). Other users can post comments under each link posted (called Publicreply in my models.py).

Here's what I want to do: for every user, I want to produce a queryset that -

(i) contains only links the user commented under

(ii) is sorted by the timestamp of the most recent comment under every link. E.g. if a link has multiple comments, I want the **most recent** comment's timestamp to sort the said link in the queryset. Note that this comment can be from anyone (not necessarily from the user herself).

Now for some simple code, straight from my **views.py**:

```
class UserActivityView(ListView):
    model = Link
    slug_field = "username"
    template_name = "user_activity.html"
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        comments_by_user = Publicreply.objects.filter(submitter=user)
        links_with_comments = [reply.answer_to.id for reply in replies_by_user.iterator()]
        qset = Link.objects.filter(id__in=links_with_comments).extra(select={'submitted_on':"SELECT max('submitted_on') FROM 'links_publicreply' WHERE 'links_publicreply.answer_to' = 'links_link.id'"})
        return qset
```

And **models.py** contains:

```
class Publicreply(models.Model):
    submitter = models.ForeignKey(User)
    answer_to = models.ForeignKey(Link)
    submitted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    description = models.TextField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(250)])

class Link(models.Model):
    submitter = models.ForeignKey(User)
    submitted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=250)
```

The SQL I wrote in the `extra()` modifier in my `views.py` under the `get_queryset()` method is not giving the desired result (I'm getting `None`). Note that I'm trying to use the `extra()` modifier to attach **the most recent timestamp** of a `publicreply` instance to its related `link`. I'll later sort the queryset according to the said timestamp.

Please help out in formulating the correct SQL in the `extra()` modifier. I use *Django 1.5* and *Python2.7*. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with `extra` specifically, or SQL at all; the problem is entirely with your Python syntax. What are you expecting `(link in links_with_comments,)` to do?

Comment: Hey Daniel. `Link.objects.filter(id__in=links_with_comments)` gives me all Links under which a user has commented. Such comments, represented by `class Publicreply` in models.py, have a timestamp (i.e. `submitted_on`). I need to attach to every link, the time stamp of the **most recent publicreply**. Whatever you see inside `extra()` is my attempt to get to this most recent time stamp. With `(link in links_with_comment)`, I'm trying to refer to the link the publicreplies have a foreign key relationship with.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: How do you advise I do this?

Comment: Changed the line of code with `extra()` to `Link.objects.filter(id__in=links_with_comments).extra(select={'submitted_on':"SELECT max('submitted_on') FROM 'links_publicreply' WHERE 'links_publicreply.answer_to' = 'links_link.id'"})` I feel I'm a step closer, but strangely the extra() part is returning `None`.

Comment: I've found that annotate() works better